# Nativescript: reading out iOS heading

Tags: ios, nativescript

I've been trying to read out the heading from CLLocationManager, but I can't seem to get it to work. On Android, I can use data from the SensorManager to figure out the heading, but iOS is different.

In essence, here's my code:

```
function startCompassUpdates(callback, options) {

  var wrappedCallback = zonedCallback(callback);
  if(!iosLocationManager) {
    iosLocationManager = new CLLocationManager();
  }
  if(CLLocationManager.headingAvailable()) {
    iosLocationManager.startUpdatingHeading();
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      console.dir("iosLocationManager.heading", iosLocationManager.heading);
      wrappedCallback(iosLocationManager.heading),
      200
    })
  } 
}
```

but it keeps on coming up empty. 
Anyone have ideas?